# Unable to auto-capture payment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm not able to auto-capture a payment in spree. I've tried that (by setting auto-capture option to true in admin panel) with `PaymentMethod::Check` method and my custom method but it always leaves payment method at `pending` state. My custom method is based on the `PaymentMethod::Check` source code and looks like that:

```
module Spree
  class PaymentMethod::CashOnDelivery < PaymentMethod
    def actions
      %w{purchase capture void}
    end

    # Indicates whether its possible to capture the payment
    def can_capture?(payment)
      ['checkout', 'pending'].include?(payment.state)
    end

    # Indicates whether its possible to void the payment.
    def can_void?(payment)
      payment.state != 'void'
    end

    def purchase(*args)
      throw 'purchase'
    end

    def capture(*args)
      ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response.new(true, "", {}, {})
    end

    def cancel(response); end

    def void(*args)
      ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response.new(true, "", {}, {})
    end

    def source_required?
      false
    end

    def auto_capture?
      true
    end
  end
end
```

However, that does not raises any exception nor changes payment state. It all looks like i'm doing something wrong, misunderstand something or spree considers my payment methods as non-autocapturable.

Thanks in advance for any clues!

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution for a payment method not auto capturing correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You should first of all need to know about Spree use of State Machine.
State of order is changed using this gem. In checkout_controller.rb, there is written "@order.next", this is where stat machine does its part and change states of order accordingly.

[This](https://www.sitepoint.com/state-machines-in-ruby/) tutorial might help you in understanding how State Machine Gem works.I think most of State Machine code of Spree is present in checkout.rb model.

I think you transaction is happening fine but state does not change because you are not handling State Machine in your class.

You need to understand other flows as well while changing such payment modification. This is one of the most difficult areas of Spree to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your `source_required?` returns `false`. Spree will not automatically process the payment if your `PaymentMethod` doesn't require a source. Even if your `auto_capture?` is set to `true`. Payments made using your PaymentMethod will need to be captured manually in admin.

From [Spree Documentation.](https://guides.spreecommerce.org/developer/payments.html#processing-walkthrough)

> If the payment method requires a source, and the payment has a source
>   associated with it, then Spree will attempt to process the payment.
>   **Otherwise, the payment will need to be processed manually**.

Solidus was cloned from Spree and their [Documentation gives even more details here](https://guides.solidus.io/developers/payments/payment-processing.html#if-process-cannot-complete):

> Payments cannot be processed using the process! method in a few
>   circumstances:
>
> - [.......]
> - The `Spree::PaymentMethod` ***does not require a payment source.***
> - [.......]